# How to get quiz test score as text without popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to implement online quiz in my blog. Below is my code after selecting all the options when user click view results it displays result score as popup.

But i want to display as result as text in the form itself as shown in the below image.

[image: score]

```js
var answers = ["A","C","B"], 
    tot = answers.length;

function getCheckedValue( radioName ){
    var radios = document.getElementsByName( radioName ); // Get radio group by-name
    for(var y=0; y<radios.length; y++)
      if(radios[y].checked) return radios[y].value; // return the checked value
}

function getScore(){
  var score = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<tot; i++)
    if(getCheckedValue("question"+i)===answers[i]) score += 1; // increment only
  return score;
}

function returnScore(){
  alert("Your score is "+ getScore() +"/"+ tot);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>How many letters are there in "ZZ"?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">3<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">4<br>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>How many letters are there in "ZZX"?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">3<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">4<br>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>How many letters are there in "V"?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">3<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">4<br>
  </li>
</ul>

<button onclick="returnScore()">View Results</button>
```

Comment: I don't see a form in your example, so in which element should the results go. Also, why the jQuery tag, I see none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a place in the DOM for the score to go.

```
<div id="show-score"></div>
```

Then use the returnScore function to place the result there instead of alerting.

```
function returnScore(){
    document.getElementById('show-score').innerHTML = 
       "Your score is "+ getScore() +"/"+ tot;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7Ly00p2z/